# Is there a name for this kind of guitar chord - not open, no barre, strings dampened?

Tags: guitar, chords, terminology

It's so convenient to say "open chord..."

[image]

or "barre chord..."

[image]

but then there are chords like these...

[image]

...where they are not open, not barred, and importantly require dampening of some of the strings.

Technique-wise they feel like a distinct category of chord fingering.

Is there a common name for this type?

I want to tell my son: "practice your ______ chords!"

"Jazz" chords seems vague, and "not-open-non-barre-muted-seventh-chords" doesn't roll off the tongue!

Comment: Not an answer, so a comment: I usually refer to them as “movable” chords. I know this might seem incredibly simple, but in fact it sums them up quite well. In the end, these are shapes that can be transposed, but without having to use a barre... BTW, that’s just what I call them; I’m interested to see what others think, and if someone can suggest a generally recognised term.

Comment: Since with chords with open strings are _open_ chords, I generally see these chords without open strings as _closed_ chords.

Comment: @DaveJacoby - that would include all barre chords as well. Not what's in question. Since all the chords mentioned have already been chritened, I suggest '*other shapes*'.

Comment: @BobBroadley - the essence of all barre chord shapes is they're 'movable' - and most guitarists see them as such. So that category would include them along with the OP's shapes. '*Other shapes*' would do.

Comment: Yes, of course that’s right, barre chords and these other chords are all movable. So I tell pupils that movable chords can be either barred or non-barred. But then, the movable aspect of barre chords is implicit, so I describe the other ones as movable. Maybe I should talk about “non-barred-movable-chords”. Arrrrrrgh!

Comment: 'Twould appear that the best answer to this question is - no.

Answer (score 3):

Howard Wright categorizes the shapes as "**other moveable**" chord shapes
http://hakwright.co.uk/guitarchords/index.html
http://hakwright.co.uk/guitarchords/explain.html#order

That's one of three categories:

- (1) Barre shapes
- (2) **Other moveable shapes**
- (3) Open string shapes

Without listing all three categories I would call them **non-barre moveable** shapes. "Practice your *non-barre moveable* chords!"

---

Before this question I had never heard a clearly distinguished name for those kinds of chord voicings or grips. But then again, I hadn't searched for one either.

Here's a really beautiful A7/C# voicing

[image: A7/C#]

In my mind I actually see that as a variation or modification of the regular A shape.

[image: A7/C# modified A barre]

But since there's no "bar", I wouldn't label it as a barre. So let it be "other moveable shape" or "non-barre moveable".

Fun fact: that A7/C# chord "X4X253" doesn't seem to be found in Howard Wright's chord shape catalog, but it is the name of a sneaker by Emporio Armani. Maybe Howard Wright didn't want names of shoes in his library.

Answer (score 3):

How about: “chords that won’t make you a rich guitar player”???

All joking aside, I would and do call these jazz chords. I know they are not exclusive to jazz but then again cowboy chords are not exclusive to country music. The fact is jazz (in its all encompassing form, swing, big band, Dixieland, bop, etc.) is where these types of chords are used the most by far. When you hear them in pop or other styles it is usually because they are going for a “jazzy” sound or vibe.

A name isn’t always a definition. Michael, you say “jazz chord” is vague. Maybe so but these types of chords and voicings are primarily used in jazz and they have a very specific makeup for the most part, 3rds, 7ths and upper tensions are favored, roots are sometimes omitted, P5ths and doubled notes are used sparingly and there are usually not more than 4 or 5 notes in a chord.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117878/discussion-on-answer-by-john-belzaguy-is-there-a-name-for-this-kind-of-guitar-ch).

Answer (score 1):

It is referred to as an open form chord and all 5 open chords, C, A, G, E, and D, form the "CAGED" system.  So you can call this the G-shape, just as you referred to the bar chord as an E-shape.  In fact you can move the open form G chord up to other positions by barring with your index finger and using fingers 3, 2, and 4 to get the other notes.

The other chords you have listed are not specifically "jazz" chords as they appear in all forms of music.  The ones that have a large interval on the bottom are sometimes call "fat" chords and are common in Big Band.  We sometimes refer to the voicing as "open" because the lower notes are far apart, usually a 6th or 7th, whereas other chord forms that have 3rds in the bass might be called "closed" form, due to the small or compressed intervals.

Quite frankly I don't think it's fair to box them up in neat categories (pun intended) as you will always find outliers, and it doesn't really help to practice only open chords today then closed chords next week.  The beauty of these forms is that many of them have a common three note shape in them allowing one to move through large jumps like a 5th, e.g. I7-->V7, etc, while keeping a large portion of the shape in tact and this creates small intervalic movement in the upper voice harmony.  So it helps more to see how many chords in a given key or progression can be fingered with some common subgroup of notes and practice moving these around.  There are some good exercise book for Jazz-Blues guitar chord progressions that emphasize this point.

Comment: I googled for "open form chord" and the search returned a grand total of three (3) pages from the whole of Internet. "Open form chords", in plural, gives 238 pages. I'm not entirely convinced that it's an actually used term. I'm not saying it's impossible though.

Comment: I'll look at my old guitar chord book collection when I get time.  Maybe I substituted another term with open.

Comment: I don't understand your first paragraph. "It's referred to as an open form chord...you can call this the G-shape." So, `3x343x` would be an open form G-shape, is that what you meant?

Comment: The "open" refers to the natural chord shapes (whatever they are) in the open position which refers to those keys and chord forms that allow opens strings to be used.  This is a common term.  So, YES, and open G-shape.  I don't know why it's causing so much confusion.  The open positions chord forms are NOT movable with standard open position fingering.  Altered fingering makes them moveable, but standard open position forms are not.  Similarly for scales in the open position.

Comment: But also, there is a concept of open voicing in harmony which I also mentioned for completeness.